# SQL Server 2012 - Rolling counter with reset

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition, rolling-computation

I am using SQL Server 2012 and want to get total of login unsuccessful attempts. My table has

```
| Login_Name | Is_Success | Login_Date |
```

My query is

```
select login_name, 
sum(case when is_success = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) over (partition by login_name, issuccess order by login_name, login_date, is_success)
from login_table
```

The query gives me results but I want the count to be reset when is_success becomes 1

```
| Login_Name | Is_Success | Unsuccessful Attempts |
| admin      | 1          | 0                     |
| admin      | 0          | 1                     |
| admin      | 0          | 2                     |
| admin      | 0          | 3                     |
| admin      | 0          | 4                     |
| admin      | 0          | 5                     |
| admin      | 1          | 0                     |
| admin      | 0          | 1                     |
```

Note: I am using **SQL Server 2012**

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic gaps and island problem. You can use a windowed `COUNT` to put the data into groups, and then use `ROW_NUMBER` for those groups:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('admin',1,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:00:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:01:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:02:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:03:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:04:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:05:00')),
                ('admin',1,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:06:00')),
                ('admin',0,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2020-10-30T20:07:00')))V(Login_Name,Is_Success,Login_Date)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT Login_Name,
           Is_Success,
           Login_Date,
           COUNT(CASE Is_Success WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Login_Name ORDER BY Login_Date) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT Login_NAme,
       Is_Success,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Login_NAme, Grp ORDER BY Login_Date) -1 AS UnSuccessfulAttempts
FROM Grps
ORDER BY Login_Name,
         Grp,
         Login_Date;
```

Comment: This looks like the correct approach and I have upvoted it - however will the `COUNT(Is_Success)` work if non-successful attempts have a value (e.g., 0, or -1)? You could use COUNT(CASE ...) similar to theirs. Also, your order by has a redundant field - maybe you meant date?

Comment: You would use a `CASE` expression instead, @seanb . I just assumed they were likely just a `1` or `0` and that's what your sample data says.

Comment: I tried running this query but it doesnt return me the result. The UnSuccessfulAttempts column always increment by 1

Comment: Sample data will help me help you, @Ankit. I only had expected results, so had to make assumptions on your data.

Comment: Sample data is in the original question

Comment: I've updated with assumptions on your data, @Ankit . As I mentioned, there's no sample data, only expected results. You have a column `Login_date`, for example, that I have no idea what is *actually* stored.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for a summary, not a log of specifics? I would approach that like so:

```
SELECT login_name, 
 ( SELECT count(*) FROM login_table
    WHERE login_name = lt.login_name
      AND login_date > ( SELECT MAX(login_date) FROM login_table WHERE login_name = lt.login_name AND is_success = 1 )
 ) AS failures
  FROM login_table AS lt
  ORDER BY 1
```

How it works:

The inner correlated subquery gets the last successful login for a user:

```
SELECT MAX(login_date) FROM login_table WHERE login_name = lt.login_name AND is_success = 1
```

The outer correlated query:

( SELECT count(*) FROM login_table
WHERE login_name = lt.login_name
AND login_date > --last successful login--
) AS failures

counts how many failures occurred after the last success.
I have not tested this. Good luck with your project!